# Google Maps API v2 Marker with Street View Image as Icon

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2, google-street-view

I'm using Google Maps Android API v2 and I've got everything set up correctly.  I have set some markers based on latitude / longitude.

How can I add the Street View image of the lat/lng as an icon?

```
/* Google Maps API v2 map set code here */
Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point)
  .title("Title")
  .snippet("Snippet")
  .icon(  StreetViewObject? ));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this api to get an image based on your latitude and longitude:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/